# In Ansible, how do I get list of roles assigned to a host?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

In a particular task I'd like to find out the list of roles assigned to the current host and change some configuration based on that. Is this possible?

Comment: Seems like an XY-problem...

Comment: True - it is. I _have_ found another way to solve the original problem, but I want to explore whether this particular approach is possible, or not.

Comment: It's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can get list of roles assigned to host via facts.
Variable 'role_names' lists roles.

```yaml
- debug: var=role_names
```